# Pass over URLs scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to do some web scraping and I wrote a simple script that aims to print all URLs present in the webpage. I don't know why it passes over many URLs and is printing a list from the middle instead from the first URL.

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = request.urlopen("http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Alphabetical.aspx?Lan=Ita&FL=%25")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

for links in soup.select('a'):
    print(links['href'])
```

Why that? Anyone could explain me what happen?

I am using Python 3.7.1, OS Windows 10 - Visual Studio Code

Comment: have you disabled javascript in browser and checked if some links are no longer present? Also, test with different parsers.

Comment: I ran it; it first prints out the alphabet links at the top, then seems to print in the correct order

Comment: The length of all the hrefs the script got was 1002 and searching in the html in the browser for 'href' got the result 1002 for me. So it's not skipping over any hrefs.

Comment: Thanks to all, I appreciate your comments. 

@QHarr I tried to disable javascript as you advice me but it doesn't solve the issue. Then I parsed also with XML but as well no improvements, it just add some more HREF but far to be the complete list.

Comment: What is the expected target number of hrefs in result?

Comment: @QHarr I don't know exactly because I don't know how to count it all. I just see that if I run the script the output start from HREF which include letter P to Z instead from A to Z.

Comment: @LuckyZakary Could you please tell me how did you count the total number of HREFs? Thank you

Comment: open the browser on that webpage > F12 to open dev tools > elements tab > Ctrl + F to pull up search box > enter [href] and press Enter. Number of matches should then show.

Comment: @QHarr great hint! thanks a lot. The total amount of [href - table#tblResult] are 978.

Comment: @QHarr but as confirmed already above by LuckyZakary, if I count all the [href] (in the browser) are 1002. The issue still remain when I run the script as above in my post.

Comment: @LuckyZakary Did you run the same script as I wrote above?

Comment: Yes I did, the script is working correctly for me.

Comment: I start to think that is a setting problem, but what could be? I've tested the same script also on Jupyter and when I run it, I receive a ModuleError: "No Module named bs4", but it exist already, I did run other scripts previously without any problems. In any case I did [!pip install bs4] again by Jupyter and nothing the same issue. Anybody know what is going on here?

Comment: @JammyDodger Which code number you see in the end (right side) of the first row when you run the above script?

Answer (score 1):

Often, hrefs just provide part (not complete) of urls. No worries.
Open it in a new tab/ browser. Find the missing part of the url. Add it to the href as string.

in the case, that must be 'http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/'.

Here is your code.

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = request.urlopen("http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Alphabetical.aspx?Lan=Ita&FL=%25")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

for links in soup.select('a'):
    print('http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/' + links['href'])
```

And this' the result.

```
http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Alphabetical.aspx?Lan=Ita&FL=A
http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Alphabetical.aspx?Lan=Ita&FL=B
http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Alphabetical.aspx?Lan=Ita&FL=C
http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Alphabetical.aspx?Lan=Ita&FL=D
http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Alphabetical.aspx?Lan=Ita&FL=E
...
http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/ComponentiAlimento.aspx?Lan=Ita&foodid=8721_2
http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/ComponentiAlimento.aspx?Lan=Ita&foodid=347_1
http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/ComponentiAlimento.aspx?Lan=Ita&foodid=2021_1
http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/ComponentiAlimento.aspx?Lan=Ita&foodid=805958_1
http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/ComponentiAlimento.aspx?Lan=Ita&foodid=349_1
```